# Pagination working but not quite right. Repeating first post on second page

Tags: php, pagination, kirby

My pagination isn't quite working. There are only 4 events and pagination is set to 3 per page. When I load the second page, it loads the first event again on its own instead of the the last post.

My code is below. I'm using the kirby content manager but I assume this stuff is pretty uniform across websites. I'm pretty sure it's not working because of the loop inside of my events loop but I have no idea how to correct it.

```
<div id="main-container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 content-block">
          <ul class="events-list">
          <?php $events = $page->children()->paginate(3);
            $i = -1;
            foreach($events as $event) {
              $i++; ?>
              <li class="event-list-item">
                <?php $calendar = page('events')->children()->nth($i)->calendar()->yaml();
                  foreach($calendar as $calendarEntry) { ?>
                      <span class="event-date">
                        <span class="date">
                          <?php 
                            $eventday=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                            echo date('j',$eventday);  
                          ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="month">
                          <?php 
                            $eventmonth=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                            echo date('M',$eventmonth);  
                          ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="year">
                          <?php 
                            $eventmonth=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                            echo date('Y',$eventmonth);  
                          ?>
                        </span>
                      </span>
                      <div class="event-list-cont">
                        <span class="meta-data">Starts:
                          <?php $eventday=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                          echo date('l',$eventday);  ?>, 
                          <?php $eventstarttime=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_time']);
                          echo date('g:i A',$eventstarttime); $eventday=strtotime($calendarEntry['_end_date']);
                          if ($eventday){ ?>
                            | Finishes: <?php echo date('l',$eventday); ?>,
                            <?php }  ?>
                          <?php $eventendtime=strtotime($calendarEntry['_end_time']);
                          if($eventendtime) {
                            echo date('g:i A',$eventendtime);
                            }  ?></span>
                        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo page('events')->children()->nth($i)->url(); ?>"><?php echo $calendarEntry['eventname'] ?></a></h4>
                        <p>
                          <?php echo page('events')->children()->nth($i)->eventwriteup()->excerpt(250); ?> <a href="<?php echo page('events')->children()->nth($i)->url(); ?>">read&nbsp;more&nbsp;→</a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <!-- Page Pagination -->
          <?php
          $list = $page->children()->paginate(3);
          $pagination = $list->pagination();
          ?>
          <nav>
            <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
              <?php if($pagination->hasPrevPage()): ?>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $pagination->prevPageURL() ?>">&larr;</a></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                <li><span>&larr;</span></li>
                <?php endif ?>
              <?php foreach($pagination->range(10) as $r): ?>
                <li><a<?php if($pagination->page() == $r) echo ' class="active"' ?> href="<?php echo $pagination->pageURL($r) ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a></li>
              <?php endforeach ?>
              <?php if($pagination->hasNextPage()): ?>
              <li class="last"><a href="<?php echo $pagination->nextPageURL() ?>">&rarr;</a></li>
              <?php else: ?>
              <li class="last"><span>&rarr;</span></li>
              <?php endif ?>
            </ul>
          </nav> ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Wall,
I'd love to help here but need more context into your code. There seems to be some repetition into your loops. Not sur why you're using a $i variable inside your loop as well. By the looks of it you could get away with something much more simple:

```
<div id="main-container">
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 content-block">
          <ul class="events-list">
          <?php $events = $page->children()->paginate(3);
            foreach($events as $event): ?>
              <li class="event-list-item">
                <?php $calendar = $event->calendar()->yaml();
                  foreach($calendar as $calendarEntry) { ?>
                      <span class="event-date">
                        <span class="date">
                          <?php 
                            $eventday=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                            echo date('j',$eventday);  
                          ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="month">
                          <?php 
                            $eventmonth=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                            echo date('M',$eventmonth);  
                          ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="year">
                          <?php 
                            $eventmonth=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                            echo date('Y',$eventmonth);  
                          ?>
                        </span>
                      </span>
                      <div class="event-list-cont">
                        <span class="meta-data">Starts:
                          <?php $eventday=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_date']);
                          echo date('l',$eventday);  ?>, 
                          <?php $eventstarttime=strtotime($calendarEntry['_begin_time']);
                          echo date('g:i A',$eventstarttime); $eventday=strtotime($calendarEntry['_end_date']);
                          if ($eventday){ ?>
                            | Finishes: <?php echo date('l',$eventday); ?>,
                            <?php }  ?>
                          <?php $eventendtime=strtotime($calendarEntry['_end_time']);
                          if($eventendtime) {
                            echo date('g:i A',$eventendtime);
                            }  ?></span>
                        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo $event->url(); ?>"><?php echo $calendarEntry['eventname'] ?></a></h4>
                        <p>
                          <?php echo $event->eventwriteup()->excerpt(250); ?> <a href="<?php echo $event->url(); ?>">read&nbsp;more&nbsp;→</a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <!-- Page Pagination -->
          <?php
          $list = $page->children()->paginate(3);
          $pagination = $list->pagination();
          ?>
          <nav>
            <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
              <?php if($pagination->hasPrevPage()): ?>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $pagination->prevPageURL() ?>">&larr;</a></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                <li><span>&larr;</span></li>
                <?php endif ?>
              <?php foreach($pagination->range(10) as $r): ?>
                <li><a<?php if($pagination->page() == $r) echo ' class="active"' ?> href="<?php echo $pagination->pageURL($r) ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a></li>
              <?php endforeach ?>
              <?php if($pagination->hasNextPage()): ?>
              <li class="last"><a href="<?php echo $pagination->nextPageURL() ?>">&rarr;</a></li>
              <?php else: ?>
              <li class="last"><span>&rarr;</span></li>
              <?php endif ?>
            </ul>
          </nav> ....
```

For more information about pagination, check this post: [Pagination](https://getkirby.com/docs/solutions/blog/pagination)